# Efficient way to pair a limited number of random elements from two separate collections

Tags: c#

I have two lists (lista and listb), each containing an unknown number of points (two ints in a struct).

I want to create a new list containing **unique** random pairings from lista and listb. So an example entry might be [12,14] where 12 is an index for lista and 14 is an index for listb.

I also want to set a maximum number of pairings when calling this function. So instead of pairing every element in lista with every element in listb, I could limit it to 200 random pairings as an example.

My first attempt at this was to simply generate every possible pairing. Shuffle that list and knock off any elements past my max. This solution isn't nearly efficient enough.

My next attempt was to make an array per original list of every possible index, shuffle those separately, and then just iterate over them both until I had the max number of pairings (or all of them). This has several problems I'm not certain how to solve. One of which, lista could have 10 million elements for all I know. Creating a new array of 10 million elements (the indices list) and shuffling that when my max pairs might only be 200? Seems silly to go that far.

I've considered just choosing random elements from both lista/listb and seeing if I've already paired them before adding them to the new list. This is also quite a silly option as a lot of time can be spent picking duplicate pairings over and over.

So, what's a good option here or is there one? I don't want to iterate over every possible combination, pairings need to be unique, removing options from a list is quite slow due to the array re-sizing when they are quite large, distribution needs to be pretty uniform in the selection process for each list, etc.

Thanks for any and all help.

Edit - I meant the unique aspect regarding the pairs themselves. So element 10 in lista could be used over and over as long as the element in listb is different each time. The only catch there is I don't want to limit lista and listb right off as I need fairly even distribution across both lists for every pairing.

Comment: Unless you're picking close to the full list, the duplicate search won't be nearly as bad as you think. What I mean is that if you're picking 200 elements out of a full list of 10 million elements, you're not going to have many duplicates.

Comment: Now, is a duplicate that you've picked an element from lista more than once, or that the exact pairing has been seen more than once? For instance, let's say the first three pairings are `(1,1) - (1,2) - (2,2)`, do you have any duplicates here? I ask because if it is unique combinations then even when picking 200 random pairs out of two lists consisting of 10.000 elements each will only have the odd duplicate every once in a while.

Comment: what should be unique? only indexes you take from two list for pairing or the points also matter?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'll edit the original too, but I meant the unique aspect regarding the pairs themselves. So element 10 in lista could be used over and over as long as the element in listb is different each time. The only catch there is I don't want to limit lista and listb right off as I want fairly even distribution across both lists for every pairing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The reason efficiency has came up as an issue here is due to the number of times this function needs to be called and with extremely varying inputs. I'd guess based on the table I'm getting my source information from, around 20% of the time the total possible pairings will actually be less than the max number of needed pairings. This function needs to be ran across each record in an external table whenever a user needs the information (multiple times per day) and right now the table has around 20 million records (this will grow).

Comment: When something is not efficient dont try to make it efficient. just look for another way. this way looking for pairs in anyway costs time. you may have to completely change what you have in mind and just look for another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Good advice for some cases, but I've yet to find a way around this problem (sometimes being more efficient is the only way). Thankfully, Rawling has given an answer that has essentially solved my problem (although it took me multiple reads to figure out what he meant).

Comment: That seems interesting. i havent read it yet but i will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates completely, you could try doing a *sparse* [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

- Create a `Dictionary<int, int> dict` that will map "indices in the Fisher-Yates array that do not hold their own index" to "the value at that index".
- For the `n`th item, pick a random number `x` from `n` (inclusive) to "size of ListA * size of ListB" (exclusive)

  - `dict[x] ?? x` is your *selected item*.
  - Store `dict[n] ?? n` in `dict[x]`.
  - Map the *selected* item back to a pair of indices (divide by size of ListA for the ListB index, modulus by the size of ListA for the ListA index).

Comment: It took me multiple reads to understand what you meant here, not because it's that difficult.. just a little challenging to put into words. I'll essentially be performing the Fisher-Yates shuffle on an array that is built as I perform the shuffle using 2D>1D and 1D>2D mapping "tricks" since I know the sizes of lista and listb. Thanks, I think it'll work just how I need it. Once I've implemented it, I'll accept this gladly.

Comment: @TimWinter Yup, the 2D>1D>2D mapping helps (easier to deal with primitive types) and using a dictionary can help if you have too many items to be able to build a `m*n` array.

Answer (score 1):

A math or statistics buff might give you a formula for evaluating this but I just wrote some test code.

The code simply picks random pairs, and every time it sees a duplicate it tries again. Then for each such "pick a random pair until unique" cycle it counts how many retries it did and tracks this. Then finally this is summed up into a global array to track the relative frequency of these things.

Here's the results after about 1 minute of execution:

```
84382319 81 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The numbers mean this:

- Out of 421912 cycles [(84382319+81)/200]:

  - 81 duplicates were found but retrying did not find a duplicate (3rd number and up is 0)
  - 84382319 unique pairs could be found on the first try without duplicates

So, obviously this will start to rise if you increase the number of pairs you want generated or lower the numbers to choose wrong, but I'm not sure this will pose a problem in practice.

Here's the [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program I used:

```
static Random R = new Random();
void Main()
{
    var a = 10000;
    var b = 10000;
    var n = 200;

    int[] counts = new int[10];
    var dc = new DumpContainer().Dump();

    while (true)
    {
        var once = Test(a, b, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < once.Length; i++)
            counts[i] += once[i];
        dc.Content = Util.HorizontalRun(true, counts);
    }
}

public static int[] Test(int a, int b, int n)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();
    var result = new int[10];

    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++)
    {
        int tries = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var av = R.Next(a);
            var bv = R.Next(a);
            var t = Tuple.Create(av, bv);
            if (seen.Contains(t))
                tries++;
            else
            {
                seen.Add(t);
                break;
            }
        }
        result[tries]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this alone will work for me due to the number of times each original list will only have 15-20 values. In that case, this method will stall the application tremendously and this function has to be callable millions of times while an end-user waits on it. I proposed we run this whole thing daily and cache the results, but I was told that's not acceptable for our purposes.

Comment: So then you can pick different implementations for different sized problems. 10 million elements, go with the hashset. 15-20 elements, go with shuffling.